# Footprint panel is grayed on Altium Designer PCB

Tags: pcb, altium, footprint, library, panel

This is a project I imported from Eagle (not so bad by the way). I resolved all schematic compilation errors. But now I am facing some small issues in the PCB part:

On the properties panel when I select any component, footprint is grayed. See picture. Not a big issue because I can still update my footprints by the menu option (all, or one by one).

Do you know why all my components seem locked? Could I revert this to a "normal" situation where footprint name and library could be modified? This way I could push to schematics modification of footprint done in PCB.

I tried to "update all component footprint" - did nothing.

*This is Altium Designer 18.1.8*

[image: grayed footprint propreties]

**EDIT:**

Ok, new components that I added since the conversion seems to work as usual. But old one are still locked.

Comment: You've neglected to ask a question.

Comment: hum. Good point. So there it is : I never been facing of this. Do you know why all my component seems looked ? and could I revert this to a "normal" situation where Footprint name and library could be modified. This way I could push to schematics modification of footprint done in PCB

Comment: Click "edit" at the bottom of your question to edit and improve it.  Do this every time you add additional information, rather than leaving it in the comments.

Comment: Have you tried unlocking primitives? (Looking at the padlock icon shown in image.)

Comment: Hi, yes but did nothing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is grayed because it is an IntLib as integrated library (locked) and not PCBlib as usually used.